# Automatic redirect with JavaScript in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I've been using the below script for years on an html site with no issues, but for some reason I can't make it work in WordPress. Upon making a selection in the drop-down box, it should redirect the visitor immediately to the new URL, but in WP nothing happens - it just sits there. Here is the live, non-working page: http://www.lawlessfrench.com/subjunctivisor/

And here is the script (with a bunch of options removed):

```
<Script language="JavaScript">
<!-- Script courtesy of http://www.web-source.net - Your Guide to Professional Web Site Design and Development
function goto(form) { var index=form.select.selectedIndex
if (form.select.options[index].value != "0") {
location=form.select.options[index].value;}}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
<FORM NAME="form1">
<SELECT NAME="select" ONCHANGE="goto(this.form)" SIZE="1">
<option value="">Choose a verb or expression</option>
<option value="http://www.lawlessfrench.com/subjunctivisor/accepter/">accepter que</option>
<option value="http://www.lawlessfrench.com/subjunctivisor/vouloir/">vouloir que</option>
<option value="http://www.lawlessfrench.com/subjunctivisor/il-est-vrai/">vrai (il est / c'est)</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Learn to use a console tool such as Firebug for Firefox, or the inspector in Chrome or Firefox, to watch / test your site.  Your site is throwing javascript errors at the rate of about 50 per second.  There's no way any javascript is going to work on that page until it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard way of doing things in WP.

1.First register your script with `wp_register_script()` , see the link for more info

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script

2.Next you should enqueue your script with `wp_enqueue_script()` , see here for more info

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

For this you have to place your inline js in a separate .js file. Also remember if you have registered the script then you only need to provide the handle in the enqueue function later on . i.e

`wp_enqueue_script( 'name_of_registered_script' );`

Comment: I tried that, but had the same problem, so switched back to just putting the js right in the page to simplify the troubleshooting.

Comment: You would probably be doing something wrong with using those functions, is this script dependent upon some other js or it's a standalone js .?

Comment: It's standalone and it's only for one page.

Comment: Yes, it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your script on js fiddle and it definately works. Here is the link for the test : http://jsfiddle.net/d9DzK/

On your live site when you change the selection the error "goto function is not defined" comes up. You have clearly defined the function though:

```
function goto(form) { var index=form.select.selectedIndex
if (form.select.options[index].value != "0") {
location=form.select.options[index].value;}}
```

So my guess is the 2 errors that show up in the javascript console after page load are breaking the javascript. From looking at the line that throws the error I believe it is because of how you included the script into your template.

I think you have an extra p tag that you do not close which is causing the error.

Try changing this:

```
<p><Script language="JavaScript"><br />
```

To this:

```
<Script language="JavaScript"><br />
```

If that doesn't fix the problem a broken html entity is still most likely the culprit.

Comment: Thank you. I was surprised by your comment, and sure enough, when I looked at my code, there was no <p> tag there - apparently it's being added by the theme. I'm playing around with it (for example, by adding actual <p> and </p> tags), but so far no luck.

Comment: @lkl It could be other javascript errors. Your script.js file is missing `});` at the end. You have it once but it needs it again.

Comment: @lkl What was the final solution?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work, so I just put it on a regular HTML page rather than a blog post.